# Why do I need to break out my dot operator for my DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html

I had this exercise to add a purple block to end of section element. The following wouldn't work:

```
let colorSect = document.querySelector('section')
let newDiv = document.createElement('div').className = 'purple'
colorSect.appendChild(newDiv) //Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

However breaking it out like this does work:

```
let colorSect = document.querySelector('section')
let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
newDiv.className = 'purple'
colorSect.appendChild(newDiv)
```

Trying to understand why it would need it broken out like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

When you write this:

```
let newDiv = document.createElement('div').className = 'purple'
```

The `newDiv` variable contains `'purple'` which is not a Node.

This is called "assignment chaining" and you can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment